# Heroku Dyno Problem. Free Hour Pool gets used by 24 hours in 12 hours

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js, heroku-api

I have my Discord bot hosted in Heroku with verified account.
I have 2 dynos but only **one turned on**

- Worker `node index.js` (ON)
- Web `npm start` (OFF)

In this case, why does the time pool gets used by *24 hours in 12 hours* (approx)?

How to delete the Web dyno?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have 2 Dynos (one for worker and one for web)? Or a single Dyno with both?

Comment: I have two dynos, worker and web but the web is never turned on, so only one I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that can drain usage hours. Try these following:

- Make sure the web dino is actually off (try to access the subdomain that they give.)
- Force deploy once
- Make sure your other projects are not draining the hours (the 1000 hours are per user not per project)
- Delete the project and create a new one